# Error of permission denied while running setting new container in python using docker client

Tags: python-2.7, docker, pycharm

I am having this very simple python script (on pycharm) where I set 'nginx' server by pulling it from the hub, this is my code:

```
import docker
import requests

client = docker.from_env()
img = client.images.pull('nginx:latest')
client.containers.run(img, detach=True, ports={'80/tcp': 8080})

r = requests.get('http://localhost:8080')

print(r.status_code)
```

I am getting the following error:
`docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))`

when I am running this code using 'ipython' via terminal I am not getting any error and everything is working as expected.

I tried to look after a solution using the network with no success.

Answer (score 1):

try to add current user to your usergroup

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

more info on https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/